# Error: "mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm getting an error when I try to use the function below.

```
require_once("connection.php");

function check_max_field_lengths($field_length_array) {
    $field_errors = array();
    foreach($field_length_array as $fieldname => $maxlength ) {
        if (strlen(trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST[$fieldname]))) > $maxlength) { $field_errors[] = $fieldname;
        }
    }
    return $field_errors;
}
```

It says:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
```

But I've already defined `$connection` in the connection.php file like so:

```
require("constants.php");
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) or die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
```

$connection works fine in my other uses, but not here.
Any idea why?

Comment: ... and the answer is **not** globals

Comment: So simple. Newbie error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pass the connection to your function

```
function check_max_field_lengths($field_length_array, $connection) {
```